# SQL Optimized Way to Calculate Aggregate Timespans

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table with *n* history entries which record the changes from active/inactive.

```
[Id]   [ParentId] [Date]                   [Status]
<guid> 0          2013-05-03 15:51:24.810  'Active'
<guid> 0          2013-05-03 15:52:10.773  'Inactive'
<guid> 0          2013-05-03 15:54:26.710  'Active'
<guid> 0          2013-05-03 17:09:27.327  'Inactive'
```

I'm trying to determine how long the item was in the "Active" status over its entire history. Iterating the history with a cursor and using `DATEDIFF` to calculate it has had terrible performance. I'm trying to avoid the use of SQLCLR, but could probably do this in memory fairly cheaply... does anyone know of a good SQL-native, performant way of accomplishing this?

Comment: The words "self join" spring to mind.  Is there a record id of some sort?

Comment: Yes, sorry, there are both a UUID column on the history table and a FK column to the parent object. - Updated the question with a better example table.

Comment: *'I'm trying to determine how long the item was in the "Active" status'* - how is an 'item' identified? Is it `[Id]`, `[ParentId]` or some other field not included? Also, can you amend the existing table design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key idea is to get the next inactive record after a given active record.

If you are using SQL Server 2012, then you can use the `lead()` function.  Otherwise, I think a correlated subquery is the simplest way to represent what needs to be done.  (You can also do this with an explicit `join`, I just think this is clearer).

```
select guid, sum(datediff(ms, t.[date], t.nextInactive)) as duration_ms
from (select t.*,
             (select min([date])
              from t t2
              where t2.guid = t.guid and t2.[date] > t.[date] and t2.status = 'Inactive'
             ) as nextInactive
      from t
      where t.status = 'Active'
     ) t
group by guid
```

Once you have the next inactive record, then just take the difference (in this case in milliseconds) and add up the values.

If the last record is an active record, then it will be ignored.  If you want that to count, then you need to use `coalesce(t.nextInactive, <some value here>)` in the outer query.

Performance will be improved if you have an index on `guid, status, date`.

Comment: That works perfect. Gonna play with `LEAD()` just to see if its any more performant, but the subquery works well!